# Как запустить bat-файл в Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++, bat

Хочу научить программу "запускать" bat файл, но не знаю как это делается.

Comment: Возможно ShellExecute - то что вам нужно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать функцию системного вызова — [`system`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) из `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: А можно поподробнее??? Там? в примере, нет никакого execute...

Comment: допустим у Вас есть файл `1.bat`. Чтобы его запустить нужно вызвать функцию

    system("Путь\\к файлу\\1.bat");

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!!!

Comment: А можете подсказать как этот бат файл можно "засунуть" в программу???
Чтобы код программы и программа находились в одном exe из которого и исполнялся бы этот бат???

Comment: Вы можете вызывать по очереди каждую команду из этого файла с помощью  `system`. Можно записать bat-файл в массив строк, а потом в цикле вызывать команды.